# Select on time.After results deadlock

Tags: go, channel

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    chan_never_used := make(chan int, 10)

    c := make(chan int, 10)
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            c <- 0
        case c <- <-chan_never_used:
        }

        println(<-c)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7hZMdITecg

The code above results in `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`.

But if I change one line:

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    chan_never_used := make(chan int, 10)

    c := make(chan int, 10)
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            c <- 0
        case n := <-chan_never_used: // This line changed
            c <- n                   // Add this line
        }

        println(<-c)
    }
}
```

It works well.

Why the first version of code results in deadlock and why could this change make the code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the standard the [select statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) contains of a bunch of [Send](https://golang.org/ref/spec#SendStmt) or [Receive](https://golang.org/ref/spec#RecvStmt) statements.

In this case it is the send statement.

Send statement is defined as:

```
SendStmt = Channel "<-" Expression .
Channel  = Expression .
```

Looking at your code:

```
case c <- <-chan_never_used:
```

The `Channel` fraction is `c`, the `Expression` fraction is `<-chan_never_used`.

So, the `select` semantics of the Send Statement of being (potentially) non-blocking is not applicable because it is the expression that blocks. And before the Send Statements semantics is applied the Expression part must be completely evaluated.